# How to specify an auto-incrementing (int) identity column using Fluent-NHibernate and MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

The title basically says it all... I'm trying to specify an auto-incrementing (int) identity column using Fluent-NHibernate and MySQL. I've tried the following variations...

> Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.Native();
>   Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.Identity();
>   Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.Increment();

...and tried setting default values on each.

Note: I'm using an int data type and have received errors such as...

> "Input string was not in a correct format."

or...

> "Field 'ID' does not have a default value'

Answer (score -3, accepted):

In MySQL you can create a column and mention its properties as AUTO_INCREMENT and DEFAULT VALUE 1 (or whatever you wish), why don't you use it?

--Cheers

Comment: When Fluent-NHibernate generates the schema, it auto generates the column with a datatype of int(11) with auto-increment. There's no default value, but setting one didn't make a difference.

Comment: Argh... Web.config was using an old connection string where an older version of the database resided. After correcting that... "Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.Identity();" worked with no problems.

Answer (score 8):

I'm using

```
public class User
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Names> Names { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Addresses> Addresses { get; set; }
    }
```

and mapping as Increment and works for me.

```
Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Increment();
```