# Dependency UPDATE/INSERT in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I’m trying to implement the following TSQL code (currently wrapped up in a stored procedure) using NHibernate. As  you can see the system has some custom sequencing implemented already.

```
DECLARE @NextSequence bigint;

UPDATE [dbo].[Sequencer] SET @NextSequence = Sequence = Sequence + 1;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Customers] (Id,Name) VALUES (@NextSequence, 'Jack');
```

The `INSERT` statement depends on `UPDATE` and the way the `@NextSequence` variable being set is important.

How can I do this in a 'single' database transaction/call using NHibernate?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options to achieve this,

1. You can use the NHibernate's `CreateSQLQuery` to pass literal SQL to the database, as such, and this way you can execute the stored procedure and not worry about individual statements.

   ```
   session.CreateSQLQuery(@"EXECUTE PROCEDURE <procedure>").ExecuteUpdate();
   ```
2. However, it seems like you are trying to increment a field (`Sequence`) before inserting a new `Customer` row with the new `Sequence` value. You [create a trigger](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/t-sql/7138.asp) to this for you, and bypass NHibernate altogether.
3. Another option is to use NHibernate mapping to specify an `AUTO-INCREMENT` field, as explain in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4002274/1250033).
4. Lastly, you could implement an NHibernate `Interceptor` to update the value on the `OnSave` event,

   ```
   public class IncrementInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor
   {
       bool OnSave(object entity, object id, object[] state, 
           string[] propertyNames, IType[] types)
       {
           // Increment Customer property value before inserting
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks and of course we can always run raw/sql queries, but the whole point is to get out of stored proc and do things in NHibernate way if possible :(

Comment: Thank you again. The issue is though db schema change is not an option in my situation thus I must use sequence tables to generate sequence numbers and neither can I go for Identity type column for auto increments (cause that would be a change in db).

Comment: I'm using MS SQL Server (to be more specific SQL Azure where there is no sequence support yet). And to my knowledge the only option we have in SQL server for auto incrementing an int type field is using IDENTITY column, or am i missing something here? thanks

Comment: I did. AUTO_INCREMENT type is used in MySQL which is equivalent of Identity column in SQL Server.  A NHibernate code snippet to auto-increment a column in SQL Server table that is not Sequence or Identity, would be very helpful, thanks

Comment: Updated my answer with a fourth option.